# silverlight grid mix static columns with dynamic

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I want to have static columns as well as dynamically generated columns in my datagrid. It works but I cannot change the order in which they're displayed. Is there any way to order them properly on the grid? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Silverlight toolkit DataGrid?  If so you can use DisplayIndex on the column e.g:

```
    var test = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    test.Header = "test";
    test.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate(); 


    MyGrid.Columns.Add(test);
    test.DisplayIndex = 3;
```